# Denied entry to Turkey

Tags: uk-citizens, turkey, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to Antalya, Turkey 4.09.2018. I went with an evisa, accepted straight away, travelling there for the 4th time with my parents wife and child.

Everyone got through except me, straight away they told me im going back. I wasn't even given the opportunity to get my luggage, the Chief Immigration Officer man handled onto plane that was leaving after learning I was not going to sign any papers. They didn't want to talk to me, didn't interrogate me but want me to sign my life away didn't make sense.

I was not given rights to appeal, I wasn't even questioned.  I was denied under "cause of prohibition indefinite entrance " I love turkey in solidarity to the economic terrorism they are facing I decided to go there. Lol what a slap in the face.

In 2017 I travelled to Istanbul, and had to wait 20mins on entrance, and on exit I had to wait 5min before my passport was returned, possibly they banned me then, but I had not committed any crime, I am ethnically South Asian (Muslim), British born in uk so probably dont want to risk me being involved with their neighbour. I wouldn't be seeking help here if I was any trouble to anyone.

I have been Turkey 3 times over the last 5 years, last visit June 2017. Each time no more than 2 weeks. I did the evisa each time and they were approved.

Some month ago I visited Bulgaria, and was told Interpol was looking for me, 30mins later I was released, i was never questioned or told anything.  I've never been stopped or questioned in UK. I've searched all categories of Interpol list, I'm not there. I had my enhanced crb done recently for work, again clean. I went to Egypt this year took 2seconds, same with Spain. I travel a lot.

1) I want to know why I was denied, what had i done, how to solve it? They have said they do not need reason.

> As in the case of other visas, respective Turkish officials at the ports of entry reserves the right to deny entry into Turkey to a holder of an e-Visa without any explanation. Best wishes, Ministry of Foreign Affairs of the Republic of Turkey

2) As i have an evisa, what is the difference in getting a visa at the embassy, will they really do the legwork for an investigation and possibly remove me from any list?

> Unfortunately Turkish Consulate can not remove your name off the ban list. If you would like to apply for a visa , you can come to the Consulate General in person with and appointment, we can send your application to our Ministery of Foreıgn for an approval. This procedure would take up to 8 weeks. Best wishes, Consulate General of Turkey, Londra

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @Murad Niney What type of visa do you have? How often have you visited Turkey recently and how much time have you been spending there?

Comment: Unless there's something you're not telling us, I'd say this might be a case of mistaken identity. It's likely that only the immigration authorities in Turkey would be able to help you.

Comment: @MuradNiney The police in the UK have a lot to do. They won't come looking for you unless what they think you're wanted for is sufficiently serious. Interpol have a [Wanted Persons](https://www.interpol.int/contentinterpol/search/) page that might give you a hint. Otherwise, I think it's back to Turkish Immigration.

Comment: I tend to agree that you have a name similar to a wanted person. Perhaps the Turkish Embassy in London would help.

Comment: My _guess_ is that Bulgaria checked a little more carefully and decided you were a different person. I have the same name, but a different birth date, than someone who was unable to pay his debts. I got a lot of phone calls.

Comment: @Murad The Bulgarian authorities stopped you because of the Interpol entry. Once they'd established that you weren't the person being sought they let you go about your business. It seems that the Turkish authorities weren't so diligent. Only they can explain their actions. You're back to the Turkish Embassy (but as you're not a Turkish citizen they may not consider it's their job to help) or Turkish immigration. You might also contact the British Foreign and Commonwealth Office and see if they can make representations on your behalf.

Comment: @Murad Maybe a long shot, but you could try contacting your local MP

Comment: I'm just watching news, Tehran, Russia and Turkey having a summit regarding Idlib a town near Turkey, could this explain the heightened security?

Comment: Just heard that it's more common than I thought, i specifically know 4 UK citizens denied, they didn't talk about it, but i did to share knowledge. One was a woman with her child, she was separated from her teenage son who travelled back alone as she was deported.